# AWS Document DB is causing RestTemplate SSL issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, aws-documentdb

I was faced SSL issue while connect to AWS document db. After setting Key Store programmatically documented db started working.

Setting SSL to Document db connection code snippet:

```
String filePath = null;
try {
    filePath = keyStoreFromCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS_NAME,
            env.getProperty(AWS_RDS_CERTIFICATE_CONTENT), keystorePassword);
    logger.info("Document DB: keystore file: {}", filePath);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException
        | IOException e) {
    logger.error("Document DB: unable to generate keystore file in temp location {}", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
if (Files.notExists(Paths.get(filePath), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
    logger.error("Document DB: AWS certificate file  {} is missing", filePath);
    return null;
}
logger.info("Document DB: FOX KEYSTORE file path : {}", filePath);
System.setProperty(SYSTEM_SSL_TRUSTSTORE, filePath);
System.setProperty(SYSTEM_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PHRASE, keystorePassword);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
        .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(mongoConnectionIdleTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        .build();
MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
pingMongoConnection(client);
```

The above code works perfectly to connect AWS document DB.

Now the issue is, in the same application I'm calling another jar file method. Internally that method is creating RestTemplate and calling the another endpoint.

```
RestTemplate temp = new RestTemplate();
temp.excahnge();
```

The above API call is throwing SSL issue:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:621)
```

Can someone please suggest me the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add the certificates require to validate the server identity in the default java truststore i.e `cacerts` or you can set the application environment to use different truststore as mentioned below.

```
@Configuration
public class TrustStoreConfig {

    @Value("${trust-store}")
    private Resource trustStore;

    @Value("${trust-store-password}")
    private String trustStorePassword;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore.getFile().getPath());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
trust-store=classpath:certificates.p12  
trust-store-password=password
```